# Q: how to Get date of file in TCL/TK?

Tags: linux, shell-script, tcl

I have a file in linux:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 quangt alphaa0   8170473 Apr 23 23:06 us_pd_syn_map.log
```

I want to get the date of the file : `"Apr 23"`

How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use either [file mtime](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/file+mtime) or [file stat](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/file+stat) to get the modification time in "Unix timestamp" format:

   ```
   set timeunix [file mtime "us_pd_syn_map.log"]
   ```
2. Format it using [clock format](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/clock+format):

   ```
   set timestr [clock format $timeunix -format "%b %d"]
   ```

   If you want different formats depending on how old the file is, compare the timestamp against [clock seconds](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/clock+seconds) which returns the current timestamp.

Comment: Thanks. It works very well